# Access Data Outside of Closure, Firebase ObserveSingleEvent // SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, closures

When I first asked this question I hadn't really done my research. But after 20+ hours on this, I have structure exactly like in Firebase docs. But, I can't access any of the data outside of the closure. Here is the struct where the data should be written in to:

```
    struct UserStruct {
        let name : String!
        let age : String!
    }
```

And when it gets called, everything is written perfect in the database, inside the closure it doesn't print nil, it does print the actual value obviously. I have already tried

```
    DispatchQueue.main.async {

    }
```

But that didn't work either, somebody guide me! Any help is appreciated, this is my last issue with Firebase.

```
     let currentUser = FIRDatabase.database().reference(withPath: "users").child((FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser?.uid)!)
        currentUser.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        let name = value?["name"] as? String
        let age = value?["age"] as? String
        self.userAdded.insert(UserStruct(name: name, age: age), at: 0) // 1
        let user = UserStruct.init(name: name, age: age) // 2

        print("1 \(user.name)")
        print("2 \(self.userAdded[0].name!)")
    })
```

I wrote two ways of getting the data, number two(2) is the way Firebase suggests, but I can't even get a hold of user outside the closer like I can with the Struct.

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. The firebase data is valid inside the closure, so for example you want to populate a tableView. You observe the nodes you want, then the data is returned inside the closure. You iterate over the snapshot and populate an array (that's defined outside the closure) and once that's done, tableView.reload (still inside the closure). From then on, you data is stored in the array and can be worked with. You don't need to do DispatchQueue.main.async at all.

Answer (score 1):

Your `user` object that you create in the closure gets deallocated when the closure finishes what it has to do. As @Jay said in the comment, you need to store the data that you get in your closure in a variable **outside** of your closure. A quick and dirty way to test this out would be to create a variable in the class you're in and assign the `user` you create in your closure to that variable and print it out to see if it worked:

```
//add a property in your class to store the user you get from Firebase
var retrievedUser: UserStruct?

let currentUser = FIRDatabase.database().reference(withPath: "users").child((FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser?.uid)!)
currentUser.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
    let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
    let name = value?["name"] as? String
    let age = value?["age"] as? String

    let user = UserStruct.init(name: name, age: age)

    //assign the user retrieved from Firebase to the property above
    self.retrievedUser = user
    //print the local copy of the retrived user to test that it worked
    print(retrievedUser)
})
```